# django compare time fields

Tags: python, django, time, comparison

I am trying to compare two date fields for the time. Here is what I am doing. My output when I print. I can see it is the same, but comparison result is `False`! Any pointers to what I am doing wrong?

```
for appt in appointment_detail:
    print(appt['start_time'])
    print(slot_time)
    print(slot_time == appt['start_time'])
```

Result:

> 2018-09-22 11:00:00+00:00
>
> 2018-09-22 11:00:00
>
> False

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since one DateTime is ***timezone aware*** and one is not, they are not equal
To compare or to check equivalence, you have to convert both to standard unit/format
Here I'm removing **timezone info** of both datetime.

```
wo_tz_slot_time = slot_time.replace(tzinfo=None)
wo_tz_appt_start_time = appt['start_time'].replace(tzinfo=None)
print(wo_tz_slot_time == wo_tz_appt_start_time)
```

Comment: Thank you very much !! That is an elegant way to compare without timezones.

Comment: this works good for equality, if I need to use `<` or `>` what should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

You compare a `datetime with time zone` with a `datetime that unaware about time zone`, you can add time zone to unaware datetime like bellow:

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime

time_zone_str = '2018-09-22 11:00:00+00:00'
date_time_str = '2018-09-22 11:00:00'

time_zone = datetime.strptime(''.join(time_zone_str.rsplit(':', 1)), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z')
date_time = datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

date_time_with_time_zone = pytz.utc.localize(date_time)
print(date_time_with_time_zone == time_zone)
```

more info on [python timezone](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/).